# Which version of OpenOffice does TAILS have?

Tags: debian, openoffice, libreoffice, tails

I can't find this information anywhere.  TAILS is based on DEBIAN which at some point switched from OpenOffice to LibreOffice.  How do I know before I download 0.23 or 1.0rc1 on my slow connection which one will have which version of OpenOffice?  Also, is it possible to put Apache OpenOffice 4 on TAILS after the fact?

Comment: As you said, TAILS is based on Debian. This means that it is very easy to install OpenOffice on it if it isn't already included. I'm sure there are plenty of guides to help you install it (if you need it).

Comment: @joejoe31b, but persistently so I don't have to download it or install it every time?  TAILS is not your average distro when it comes to that i don't think

Comment: By default TAILS is forgets what you were doing last, and erases all evidence of you using it. So yes, you will need to install OpenOffice each and every time you boot into it. Admittedly, you can always install it at the Live CD level, or use a persistent volume to bypass this restriction (but it can compromise the security offered by TAILS if done incorrectly).

Comment: @joejoe31b, right, so how can I find out which version it comes with, or install it at the Live CD level as you said (if in fact the version it comes with is still too old for my needs)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has OpenOffice.org 3, even in Tails 1.0 (based on Debian 6.0.3).  Apache OpenOffice 4 has to be installed separately.  Debian Wheezy 7 apparently adopted LibreOffice 4 instead, so when Tails catches up with Debian 7, it may have LibreOffice too.